# Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom in the subpixel precision era

Tags: javascript, dom

I've found the classic [MDN formula](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#Determine_if_an_element_has_been_totally_scrolled) to check if content has been scrolled to the bottom,

```
element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
```

**doesn't** work for all cases any more. For example, if you change the scale of content to something bigger than 100% for the [demo page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#scrollHeight_Demo) you will not get the right result. This happens because now browsers use [subpixel precision](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/_Q7A4AQBFKY) on elements. Particularly `scrollTop` for not 100% scale is a fractional value now. Actually the problem happens because of `===` sign in the formula above.

So what is the simplest, but still reliable, solution?

Comment: This also happens on any displays with devicePixelRatio not `1` causing CSS pixels to be scaled, even if the elements themselves are not scaled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom (not just the window, but any element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom-not-just-the-window-but-any-element)

Comment: For reference, the answer here by Konstantin (using Math.abs) exists on the canonical)

Comment: (*"era"* does not appear to be a misspelling of *"area"*. It does appear to refer to time (evolution of web browsers over time).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My current solution:

```
function isContentScrolledToBottom(element) {
    const rest = element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop;
    return Math.abs(element.clientHeight - rest) < 1;
}
```

It checks if the element is scrolled to bottom with ±1 accuracy.

Comment: @trusktr  Problem with these solution is this also fires once when you scroll back up from bottom.

Comment: @Toniq Yeah, I don't think there's a perfect solution. You may have to adjust the number `1` depending on other factors like zoom or scale. Do you have an example? Would be interesting to see your issue and see what we can do.

Comment: I had to use `<= 1` instead of `< 1`. Reduced test case: https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/30958

Answer (score 0):

This function triggers whenever you scroll, and then you can do something that you want to do.

```js
  window.onscroll = function() {scrolled()};
  function scrolled() {
    fixed = document.body.scrollTop > 20 ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20 ?
      "Am Going Down" : "Am Going Up"
  }
```